# Parse a JSON Object

Tags: ruby, json

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
{
 "a" : "test", 
 "b" : "test", 
 "c" : [{"d": "test data", "f": ['e','f','g']}, 
        {"f": "test data", "f": ['e','f','g']}
       ], 
  "d" : [{"g": "test data", "f": ['e','f','g']}, 
         {"h": "test data", "f": ['e','f','g']}
        ]  
}
```

I need to parse this and display it in a tree format. Could somebody show some direction please. I am working on ruby.

Comment: Yup, those 4 fs need to be surrounded in quotes

Comment: pardon me, i have corrected it now. The example was with reference to a similar structure for my real time data.

Answer (score 2):

For a JSON parser, look at [JSON.org](http://json.org/)

Listed there:

- [json](http://json.rubyforge.org/)
- [yajl-ruby](http://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby)
- [json-stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream)

Comment: @tjadeson : I had a look into yajl ruby. I am able to parse the whole object using    json = File.new('file.json', 'r')
 parser = Yajl::Parser.new 
 parser.parse(json) do |hash|
 puts hash.inspect
end This enables me to render the whole object. How do i access the individual name value pairs eg - value of [c]